# How to randomize a set of numbers

Tags: c++

Lets say I wanted the user input to be randomized.
Like if the user inputted "1234567890"

The output would be like "5684319027"
Or any random number, as the numbers got randomized.

So how would I randomize a user input?

Comment: Use [`std::shuffle`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/shuffle/)

Comment: @qxz I'm a bit of a noob, so where would I put it in the code? At the beginning, before the input or after?

Comment: If you get the input as a string, you could then use `std::shuffle` on it, which would rearrange the characters. Then you'd use the string for whatever you need it for. I'll make an answer

Comment: Alright, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`std::shuffle`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/shuffle/) to randomize the order of elements of pretty much any ordered structure. You can use this on an `std::string`, which would rearrange the individual characters. Here's an example of usage:

```
// at the top of your file
#include <algorithm>

// in your main code
std::string str; // define a string variable
std::cin >> str; // get user input into the string

// shuffle the string with a default random engine
std::shuffle(str.begin(), str.end(), std::default_random_engine(std::random_device{}()));

// use the now-shuffled string...
```